# Reset size of an embedded object to its "natural" size in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, resizing

Embedded objects typically have a "natural" size. For example a 200x200 image with 100 dpi has a natural size of 2x2 inches. Similarly, a MathType formula has a natural size in which its native font size is displayed correctly, i.e. such that the 12pt letter "x" in the formula is also displayed as 12pt in Visio.

Now, if for example you scale a MathType formula, its font size and kerning are all messed up. Is there a way to reset the size of an object to its "natural size"? In Word 2010 you can do this using in the "Format Object" dialog. Go to the "Size" tab and click the button labeled "Reset", or enter 100% in both X and Y dimension.

*Is there a way to do the same thing in Visio?*

Comment: In Visio no information is kept about the image's original size. so there is no built-in way to do this. You could implement this yourself by saving the image height and width cells in User-defined cells in the shapesheet editor, then you could restore these values manually whenever you wanted to. You could create macros and event-handlers but unless you were doing this all the time I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: @PaulHerber: But there must be some way to get the original size of an embedded object. Regardless of whether Visio *stores* this size, it is available when initially embedding the object. For example, try embedding a 5x5 cm Visio drawing inside another Visio document. It will initially appear with size 5x5 cm. That is an inherent property of the embedded document, not something the containing document decides. Maybe there is a way to access this information using JavaScript... uh, I meant VBA of course.?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. Open the shape's Shapesheet, find the appropriate cell and make the formula entry blank and then press enter. That will reset the cell to its default value.

(To be able to see the shapesheet you need to enable developer mode). This is in the Options dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this with a "MathType 6.0 Equation" object. After deleting the formulas for "Width" and "Height" under "Shape Transform", both fields display "No Formula". But the shape in my drawing now appears to have a width and height of 0, instead of its natural size. The same happens when I try this with an image or a rectangle shape. Can you elaborate what you did to make this work?

Comment: That is not a normal Visio shape.It will have no master object from which it can restore the default value.

Comment: But that's what the question is about. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I updated the question to make that point more clear.